# CMake: Link list of libs from environment variable

Tags: cmake, linker-errors, cmakelists-options

Linking against a list of libs using CMake works for me if I put the following lines into CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(HelloWorld)

set( MY_LIBRARIES mylib1 mylib2 mylib3 )

add_executable( HelloWorld HelloWorld.cxx )

target_link_libraries( HelloWorld ${MY_LIBRARIES} )
```

However, I'm actually storing this list centrally in an environment variable in my .bashrc

```
export MY_LIBS=mylib1:mylib2:mylib3
```

in order to have to modify it only once for all projects and also because the Eclipse CDT IDE which I also use sometimes handles this as is without problems.

Now, I just can't get CMake to parse this environment variable properly. I've tried several related approaches from this forum using strings and list conversion, e.g.

```
string( REPLACE ":" " " MY_LIBRARIES $ENV{MY_LIBS} )
```

but to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: For obtain a **list** you need to replace colon with **semicolon**, not with a *space*.

Comment: Wow, that's embarassingly easy. The _message_ command I used for output was misleading me... :/